# Check for Null Values in R tis

Tags: r, dataframe, gam

I rarely use R, but need for a helper function that somebody has given me. I have the following line:

```
league_model_19 <- gam(SHOT_MADE_FLAG ~ ti(LOC_X) + ti(LOC_Y) + ti(LOC_X, LOC_Y), data = shots)
```

But, when I run it, the following error message is displayed:

```
Error in ti.default(LOC_X) : 
  'tif' and 'freq' cannot both be NULL if 'x' is not a ti
```

I saw online somebody write code along the lines of:

```
if(is.null(tif)){
    if(is.null(freq))
      stop("'tif' and 'freq' cannot both be NULL if 'x' is not a ti")
    else tif <- freq2tif(freq)
  }
```

But I don't know how to integrate this into my current line, or if there is a more efficient way to do this. Does anybody know how to get rid of this error message so I can proceed with my code? Let me know if more details are needed.

Edit: Added minimal dataframe to reproduce error (player_id and player_name aren't used here, just left in there). This is the data that is in 'shots' as called in the line of code I shared:

```
PLAYER_ID,PLAYER_NAME,LOC_X,LOC_Y,SHOT_MADE_FLAG
1627759,Jaylen Brown,-20,19,0
1627759,Jaylen Brown,-29,168,1
1627759,Jaylen Brown,7,30,1
1627759,Jaylen Brown,9,6,0
1627759,Jaylen Brown,-176,186,0
```

Comment: Please post a minimal dataset to reproduce the error

Comment: Minimal dataset added.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you either don't have the *mgcv* package loaded, or you have the *tis* package loaded *after* *mgcv* and the former is masking the latter.

If you didn't load *mgcv*, add `library('mgcv')` to your script before fitting the `gam()`.

If you have *mgcv* loaded but also loaded the *tis* package, both packages provide a `ti()` function and it seems the *tis* one is being found first on the search path. Your best option is to use the fully qualified name for the `ti()` so that you inform R as to which `ti()` you want to use.

Try:

```
league_model_19 <- gam(SHOT_MADE_FLAG ~ mgcv::ti(LOC_X) + 
                         mgcv::ti(LOC_Y) + 
                         mgcv::ti(LOC_X, LOC_Y),
                       data = shots)
```

You could also change the script to load *mgcv* after *tis* but this might cause later problems when you use the `ti()` from the *tis* package; in which case you could use `tis:ti()` in those places.

Comment: Hmmm, this gave me "invalid type (list) for variable 'mgcv::ti(LOC_X)'", any ideas? Again, I am a complete novice in R, so my apologies for any simplistic questions.